# Alternative layout is not been applied

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

I just create a menu item type (Single Article) and associated an article to it.

Then I created an default.php version, called single.php

So I open this article options and select this file on Alternative Layout dropdown menu.

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is little information on what you are trying to achive, so I am doing a lot of guessing.

The recommended way to solve this would be to a template override. Here are some good reads:

[How to override the output from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)

[Understanding Output Overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)

[Layout Overrides in Joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla)

[Tutorial: Taking Advantage of Alternative Layouts for Articles and Modules](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-feb-2013/item/1059-tutorial-taking-advantage-of-alternative-layouts-for-articles-and-modules)

Hope this helps!